# SWF file rendering in c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm working on a Visual studio mfc project that, I have to render SWF file and get pixel color in a specific frame?

How can I start? and dose any one have any helpful resource? 
thx ,GL

Answer (score 2):

Either you can:

- use ffmpeg to extract frames to pngs and then load them and then take your pixel - [article](http://stream0.org/2008/02/howto-extract-images-from-a-vi.html)

or

- use DirectShow with samplegrabber filter to extract frame data in real-time and get your pixels - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377544%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Do you have any Link that can help me ? swf -> PNG or your second response?